# Scala: how to write nodeBuffer to a single xml file

Tags: xml, scala, xml-deserialization

I am trying to write multiple elements to a single xml file.

If I enclose `<elem1>` and `<elem2>` in a root element `<root></root>`, at the beginning and end of `getXML()`, `getXML()` will return an `Elem`, resulting in the `scala.xml.XML.save(...)` method working.

However, this is not an option for me. 
Please show me how to write multiple elements into a single xml file.

```
def getXML(): NodeBuffer = {
  <elem1>hello</elem1>
  <elem2>Sample text</elem2>
}

val test = getXML()
scala.xml.XML.save("test2.xml", test, "UTF-8", false, null) // Does not works
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use scala.xml.XML.save to write multiple elements to a file.   The solution will be writing the whole string <elem1>hello</elem1><elem2>Sample text</elem2> into the test2.xml file.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to write multiple root elements? Don't. Just don't.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.xml.XML.save` stores a single Node (i.e. a single root element)

Storing multiple xml documents (i.e. multiple root nodes) in a single file is not supported directly by the API.

Instead, just render each `Node` in the buffer as `String` (possibly using `scala.xml.PrettyPrinter`), and write each string to a file through your preferred means of writing strings to files.

However doing this probably is a bad idea. Having files with multiple XML root elements is asking for troubles.